# Filter out duplicate Users Asp.Net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, ado.net

So I made a Registration page and a SQL table(Students Table) in the back end.  In the code behind of my registration page.aspx I've got a sql query to count the number of StudentName in the db and if the count is equal to 1 then inform the user attempting to register that the student already exist in the database.  However every time I test it the count is always 0, even when I register using a student name that is already in the db.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkUser = "select count(*) from Students where StudentName='" + txtStudentName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("Student already exist");
            }


            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Are you using MySql or Sql Server? Because the question is tagged MySql, but you're using the Sql Server ADO.Net provider. MySql and Sql Server are two very different relational database engines.